# Need to retrieve all records in table A and only single one in table B that is the last updated

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have to retrieve certain records in TABLE_A - then need to display the last time the row was updated - which is in TABLE_B (however, there are many records that correlate in TABLE_B). TABLE_A's TABLE_A.PK is ID and links to TABLE_B through TABLE_B.LINK, where the schema would be:

```
TABLE_A
===================
ID          NUMBER
DESC        VARCHAR2

TABLE_B
===================
ID          NUMBER
LINK        NUMBER
LAST_DATE   DATE
```

And the actual table data would be:

```
TABLE_A
===================
100         DESCRIPTION0
101         DESCRIPTION1

TABLE_B
===================
1     100   12/12/2012
2     100   12/13/2012
3     100   12/14/2013
4     101   12/12/2012
5     101   12/13/2012
6     101   12/14/2013
```

So, I would need something to read out:

```
Result
====================
100   DESCRIPTION0    12/14/2013
101   DESCRIPTION1    12/14/2013
```

I tried to join different ways, but nothing seems to work:

```
select * from
(SELECT ID, DESC from TABLE_A WHERE ID >= 100) TBL_A
full outer join
(select LAST_DATE from TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM = 1 order by LAST_DATE DESC) TBL_B
on TBL_A.ID = TBL_B.LINK;
```

Comment: If you have any choice in the matter, the column name DESC makes for some tough-to-read SQL, since it is a key word for ORDER BY. Makes me want to make a table with columns 'SELECT', 'FROM',  'ON' just to make the SQL a bit harder for non-computers to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to join `table_a` with an aggregate query on `table_b`:

```
SELECT    table_a.*, table_b.last_date
FROM      table_a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   link, MAX(last_date) AS last_date
           FROM     table_b
           GROUP BY link) table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.link
```

Comment: "LAST_DATE" is not a column in TABLE_A so when attempting, I get error: ORA-00904: "LAST_DATE": invalid identifier for line 1

Comment: @user2200186 indeed, mea culpa. That should have been `table_b.last_date` - fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the most recent date, think aggregation and join.  The extra levels of subqueries do not help.  Something like:

```
select a.id, a.desc, max(last_date)
from table_a a join
     table_b b
     on a.id = b.link
where a.id >= 100
group by a.id, a.desc;
```

Note:  I doubt a `full outer join` is necessary, although you can keep that if you have join keys that don't match between the tables.  Perhaps a `left join` is appropriate.

I should point out that if you want more fields from `b`, then your initial inclination to use `row_number()` is correct.  But the query would look like:

```
select a.id, a.desc, max(last_date)
from table_a a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by link order by last_date desc) as seqnum
      from table_b b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.link and b.seqnum = 1
where a.id >= 100
group by a.id, a.desc;
```

Comment: "LAST_UPDATE" is not a column in TABLE_A, so when attempting either, I get:

Comment: "LAST_DATE" is not a column in TABLE_A so when attempting, I get error: ORA-00904: "LAST_DATE": invalid identifier